# How can we write $B\setminus(A\setminus B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've tried doing it through Venn diagrams and found it equal to $B$. Is there a way to do this with a written method?

I can't figure out the expansion of $(A\cap B^{\complement})^{\complement}$.

Comment: use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67861/show-that-a-setminus-b-setminus-c-equiv-a-setminus-b-cup-a-cap-c

Answer (score 4):

We have that $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$, where $B^c$ is the complement of the set $B$. Hence, using De Morgan's law and the distributive property, 
$$
B\setminus(A\setminus B)=B\cap(A\setminus B)^c=B\cap(A\cap B^c)^c=B\cap(A^c\cup B)=(B\cap A^c)\cup B=B.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, $B \setminus (A \setminus B)$ is what you get by starting $B$ and removing all the elements of $A$ which are not in $B$. Since you're removing things from $B$ which aren't elements of $B$, you remove nothing, so the set is equal to $B$.

Now let's turn this intuition into a proof.

We'll prove that $B \setminus (A \setminus B) = B$ by double-containment, i.e. by proving that each set is a subset of the other.

- Since part of what it means to say that $x \in B \setminus (A \setminus B)$ is that $x \in B$, it follows immediately that $B \setminus (A \setminus B) \subseteq B$.
- Suppose $x \in B$. Then $x \not \in B$ is false, and so $x \in A \setminus B$ is false, i.e. $x \not\in A \setminus B$. But then $x \in B$ and $x \not\in A \setminus B$, sot hat $x \in B \setminus (A \setminus B)$. Hence $B \subseteq B \setminus (A \setminus B)$.

It follows that $B \setminus (A \setminus B) = B$ by double containment.

---

*Side-note: You could, as you tried to do, proceed by doing a bunch of algebraic computations with unions, intersections and complements. In my opinion it's far better practice (on several levels) to get intuition for what the set operations mean and use that intuition to derive a direct proof.*

Answer (score 0):

**Logical approach**

It is good practice to think about this in terms of an element $x$ in the set. Suppose $x\in B\setminus (A\setminus B)$. This is the same as writting $x\in B\cap (A\cap B')'$. From this, we have that $x\in B$, and $x\in (A\cap B')'$, which tells us that $x\in B$ and $x\notin A\cap B'$. The latter of these conditions gives us two cases. If $x\notin A\cap B'$, then $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B'$. We have then that $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$ or $x\in B$ and $x\notin B'$. But if $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$, x\in B. And if $x\in B$ and $x\notin B'$, then $x\in B$ as well, such that $B\setminus (A\setminus B)=B$.

**Algebraic approach**

Of course, we can also do this algebraically. We have,

$$B\setminus (A\setminus B)=B\cap (A\cap B')'.$$ Then using DeMorgan's law which states that $(A\cap B)'=A'\cup B'$, we have that this is equal to, $$B\cap(A'\cup B).$$ By the distributive law then, we have, $$(B\cap A')\cup(B\cap B)=(B\cap A')\cup B=B,$$ as the user before me pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align*}
x\in B\setminus(A\setminus B)
&\Longleftrightarrow x\in B\text{ and }x\notin A\setminus B\Longleftrightarrow x\in B\text{ and }\left(x\notin A\text{ or }x\in B\right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left(x\in B\text{ and }x\notin A\right)\text{ or }\left(x\in B\right)\Longleftrightarrow x\in (B\setminus A)\cup B = B
\end{align*}
$$